# How to retrieve the value of html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retrieve the value inside a "blockquote" and show it in a textbox:

```
<blockquote id="1" class="quote">"Hello guys1"</blockquote>
<blockquote id="1" class="quote">"Hello guys2"</blockquote>
<blockquote id="1" class="quote">"Hello guys3"</blockquote>
```

By clicking an event invoked and thats what I tried:

```
events : {
    "click #1" : "renderInputBox"
},
renderInputBox : function(){
    var divElement = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inputText").value = divElement;
}
```

but when I click on them nothing is shown. I also tried with different IDs but again it does not recognize when I click. I also tried div element since I thought blockquote is not sensible to invoke click event. but again no success.

```
<blockquote class="quote"><div id="1">"Hello guys1"</div></blockquote>
```

Any idea? The problem is that the function is never invoked!! because it does not recognize when I click on block quote or div element!

Comment: this markup is not valid since you can't have several elements with the same `id` attribute

Comment: id of each element should be unique. correct your code.

Comment: You are not allowed to assign same ID to more than one element. Please assign different IDs to each.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
<blockquote id="a" onClick="block1();" class="quote">"Hello guys1"</blockquote>

function block1() {
    alert($('blockquote#a').html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
<blockquote id="1" class="quote">"Hello guys1"</blockquote>
<blockquote id="2" class="quote">"Hello guys2"</blockquote>
<blockquote id="3" class="quote">"Hello guys3"</blockquote>
<input id="testid" type="text" name="testfield" value="">
```

and in your JS;

```
$( ".quote" ).click(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  $( "#testid" ).val(text);
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ayz8a/)** is a working demo.

Comment: thanks the problem is that when I click the event does not invoked!! so the function is never called!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.quote').click(function () {
              alert($(this).html());
          });

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the code after DOM is ready?

Try with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //do stuff here..
}
```

If you did this before, then try to get all blockquote elements at all with document.getElementsByTagName("blockqoutes"), but id must be fine too if you use different.

Also try to avoid start ID-s with numbers!